# Flash / ActionScript 3: Load .FLV file into a MovieClip and start playing that FLV file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How can I load a FLV file into a MovieClip (lets call the instance "flvPlaceHolder") and start playing that FLV file.. using ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 4):

Not explicitly answering your question, but there are a number of open source FLV players in the wild. I'd approach the problem by grabbing one of those and seeing how they handle playing video.

[FPlayer](http://as3flvplayer.sourceforge.net/) would be an excellent starting point. [Here is the class](http://as3flvplayer.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/as3flvplayer/as3flvplayer/source/fPlayerEx.as?revision=1.2&view=markup) that is doing the work. It is fairly straight forward, but using a project like this would probably save you some time.

This snippet should do the trick in an extremely bare bones fashion:

```
var vid:Video = new Video(320, 240);
addChild(vid);

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
vid.attachNetStream(ns);

var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;

ns.play("externalVideo.flv");
```

[from here](http://www.quip.net/blog/2007/flash/how-to-load-external-video-as3)

Comment: Thanks. But.. Yeah.. Didn't really answer my question :)

Answer (score 2):

To do this locally - cut and paste the following code in the first frame of your flash file. Of course change the name at the end.

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; 

var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
var stream:NetStream;
var video:Video = new Video(1280,960);
var metaObj:Object = new Object();

function onMetaData(data:Object):void
{

}

connection.connect(null);
stream = new NetStream(connection);
stream.client = metaObj;
metaObj.onMetaData = onMetaData;
video.attachNetStream(stream);
addChild(video);
stream.play("name_of_flv.flv");
video.x = 0;
video.y = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var video:Video = new Video();
addChild(video);

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.client = {};
ns.client.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;
ns.client.onCuePoint = ns_onCuePoint;
ns.play("http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/cuepoints.flv");

video.attachNetStream(ns);

function ns_onMetaData(item:Object):void {
    trace("metaData");
    // Resize video instance.
    video.width = item.width;
    video.height = item.height;
    // Center video instance on Stage.
    video.x = (stage.stageWidth - video.width) / 2;
    video.y = (stage.stageHeight - video.height) / 2;
}

function ns_onCuePoint(item:Object):void {
    trace("cuePoint");
    trace(item.name + "\t" + item.time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As subha pointed out, its done using the NetStream class... however, that class in particular is quite hard to work with, and very uncoherent with the rest of the language...

I would strongly advice you to use some library, class or component to wrap it up. The FLVPlayback component in Flash (without any skins), in contrast with all the other built-in components in Flash, is really straight forward and very easy to use ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var flvPlaceHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();    

var vid:Video = new Video(320, 240);
flvPlaceHolder.addChild(vid);
addChild(flvPlaceHolder);
flvPlaceHolder.x = stage.stageWidth/2-vid.width/2;
flvPlaceHolder.y = stage.stageHeight/2-vid.height/2;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
vid.attachNetStream(ns);

var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;

ns.play("mario.flv");
```