# How to get ByteArray of a Video?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, actionscript, flash-cs6

I am using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055907/2456028) to load a FLV file to my project, it's very simple. It works, but I would like to get the bytes (as ByteArray) after I load the video. Is there any way I can perform this procedure?

For convenience, I was using the `File` object (Adobe AIR) to load the file, but have not found a way to convert the bytes to a `Video` object.

Does anyone have any idea how I can load a video file and, after loading, get the ByteArray of this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        connection.connect(null);
        var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(connection);
        var client:Object = {};
        client.onMetadata = function():void{};
        stream.client = client;

        var video:Video = new Video();
        addChild(video);
        video.attachNetStream(stream);

        stream.play(null);
        stream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);

        var file:File = new File("path/to/your/video.flv");
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

        // this gives you access to the raw bytes of the file
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        fileStream.readBytes(bytes);

        // this adds the bytes to the NetStream and begins playback
        stream.appendBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: Thank you!... I would like know, what `stream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN)`  line do?

Comment: tells the byte parser expects a file header and starts at the beginning of a file.