# AS3- how to disable FLVPlayback seeker?

Tags: flash, video, actionscript, flv, flvplayback

I want to show a video that is unskippable, so i need to be able to disable the ability to use the seeker. I tried to make it visible=false, but it doesn't work. I want to be able to keep the time that is why i can't use any of the premade skins that has no seekers on it.

Comment: A bit of hacking, but it is not impossible. Unlike component structure, that might have private fields, the display list structure is transparent and fully accessible. You need to analyse the structure of **FLVPlayback** and set **mouseEnabled** and **mouseChildren** to **false** on the exact objects, that represent the seeker.

Comment: ok will try that

Answer (score 2):

I suggesting you to use Video class instead of Video Player components to be free to do any thing you want to do. it is not to hard to use Video class to load an external video file.

Try it : [Flash / ActionScript 3: Load .FLV file into a MovieClip and start playing that FLV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055866/flash-actionscript-3-load-flv-file-into-a-movieclip-and-start-playing-that-f)